# Send audio output to two devices with AudioGraph in an UWP app

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

I try to send the input from a microphone to the speaker and a connected headset simultaneously. 
I know how to do this with a file and a device but I don't know how to connect the second device with an output node and attach it to the graph. 
I can create nodes with CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync but I have no clue hwo to associate the device with the node.
For one device it works when I give the device as the PrimaryRenderDevice in the settings when the graph is created.
This is the working code for one output device. I don't know how fix this to make it work for two output devices.

```
private async Task CreateAudioGraph()
{
       AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Speech);
        settings.QuantumSizeSelectionMode = QuantumSizeSelectionMode.LowestLatency;
        settings.DesiredRenderDeviceAudioProcessing = Windows.Media.AudioProcessing.Raw; // this is also set automatically when LowestLatency is set
        settings.PrimaryRenderDevice = OutputDeviceForInput;

        CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);

        if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            // Cannot create graph

            ConnectionStatus = String.Format("AudioGraph Creation Error because {0}", result.Status.ToString());
            return;
        }

        graphForInputDeviceNo1 = result.Graph;
        ConnectionStatus = "Graph successfully created!";


        // Create a device input node using the selectedt input device
        CreateAudioDeviceInputNodeResult deviceInputNodeResult = await graphForInputDeviceNo1.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Speech, graphForInputDeviceNo1.EncodingProperties, FirstInputDevice);

        if (deviceInputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            // Cannot create device input node
            ConnectionStatus = String.Format("Audio Device Input unavailable because {0}", deviceInputNodeResult.Status.ToString());
            return;
        }

        deviceInputNode = deviceInputNodeResult.DeviceInputNode;

        // Create the first device output node
        CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult deviceOutputNodeNo1Result = await graphForInputDeviceNo1.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
        if (deviceOutputNodeNo1Result.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            // Cannot create device output node
            ConnectionStatus = String.Format("Audio Device Output unavailable because {0}", deviceOutputNodeNo1Result.Status.ToString());
            return;
        }

        deviceOutputNodeNo1 = deviceOutputNodeNo1Result.DeviceOutputNode;

        // Create the second device output node
        CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult deviceOutputNodeNo2Result = await graphForInputDeviceNo1.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
        if (deviceOutputNodeNo2Result.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            // Cannot create device output node
            ConnectionStatus = String.Format("Audio Device Output unavailable because {0}", deviceOutputNodeNo2Result.Status.ToString());
            return;
        }
        deviceOutputNodeNo2 = deviceOutputNodeNo2Result.DeviceOutputNode;

        ConnectionStatus = "Device Output connection successfully created";


        deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutputNodeNo1);

        ConnectionStatus = "Device Input connection successfully created";
        deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutputNodeNo2);

        // Because we are using lowest latency setting, we need to handle device disconnection errors
        graphForInputDeviceNo1.UnrecoverableErrorOccurred += Graph_UnrecoverableErrorOccurred;
        graphForInputDeviceNo1.Start();  // erst damit geht es los
}
```

Comment: There is a similar case, please refer it in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119818/audiograph-throws-xaudio2-e-invalid-call-on-second-frame-input-node).

Comment: I cannot see how this is similar. I don't want any frame inputs or whatever. I just want to send my output to two devices, e.g. a Headset and the speakers but I have no clue hwo to setup the two output nodes.

Comment: Hey @Frank , did you ever find a solution to output audio to two devices using AudioGraph?

Comment: Hi Allen, no I didn't. But I haven't tried it since then.

Comment: Thanks for the response! As far as I can tell you can only have one output device per graph. This seems very strange, given the design of this whole framework, but the actual code API seems pretty clear, unless I’m missing some method somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiograph.createdeviceoutputnodeasync?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Media_Audio_AudioGraph_CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync) is a bit confusing:

> Creates a new AudioDeviceOutputNode that outputs audio data from the audio graph to the system's default output device, such as speakers or headphones.

In fact, the output device is not necessary the system's default output device. However, since you are not able to change the `Device` property of the node, and the constructor does not give you that option, it seems it must be from the system settings.

However, there are another place we can set this up: the [AudioGraphSettings class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiographsettings?view=winrt-20348) allows you to set the [PrimaryRenderDevice property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiographsettings.primaryrenderdevice?view=winrt-20348), and this is actually the device will be used when creating the output node.

You can try the following:

```cs
var settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Other);
settings.PrimaryRenderDevice = device_other_than_system_output;

var ag_result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);
var ag = ag_result.Graph;

var result = await ag.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
assert(result.DeviceOutputNode == device_other_than_system_output);
```

Technically, this didn't solve your problem since a `AudioGraph` is still not able to have two output nodes. However, you can try to create multiple `AudioGraph`s that consumes the same input(s), and output to different render devices, to have the same effect as you wish.